# Managing and differentiating parallel sessions in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, parallel-processing

The question is, can I, using Spring or JS, differentiate 2 pages, opened parallel in one browser. For example, I don't want a situation

1. User opens window 1 with one list of options, stored in session.
2. User goes to another page and opens window 2 with another list of options by the same names and they overwrite options in session
3. User goes to window 1, submits the form with options from window 2 and loses everything from window 1.

There is no logging in or anything on the page to help differentiate parallel sessions.
And it's principal to make this work in parallel pages

Comment: Maybe there is a possibility to do something like this:
`onLoad(){window.session["session"] = getSession()}` and than
`onClick(){setSession(window.session["session"]}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different id for each window. This id may come from hidden field in your form and be generated by random.

---

You start with adding a hidden field to your form, holding unique id of this form:

`<input type="hidden" name="suffix" value="50bd324e7a" />`

Then, you use this value as a suffix to all variables coming from this form.
Session keys are strings, so there's no problem in adding suffix to them in order to set/get a value.

Using your scenario, it'll go like this:

1. *User opens window 1 with one list of options, stored in session.*

   Store data adding your suffix to keys, e.g variable `email` will be stored in session variable `email_50bd324e7a`.
2. *User goes to another page and opens window 2 with another list of options by the same names and they overwrite options in session*

   Same thing here, but it's a different form, with different id, therefore variable names will be different.
3. *User goes to window 1, submits the form with options from window 2 and loses everything from window 1.*

   On submit, you read the value of hidden field and use it to get data from session.

---

The other approach is to use those unique id as keys directly, and under the keys store array of all form variables. The idea is pretty similar (and maybe the code will be more clean).

E.g:

All variables for form with id `50bd324e7a` are stored (as a map) in session variable named `50bd324e7a`. So in order to get a value of e.g. form variable `email`, you need to call `session.getAttribute(50bd324e7a)` and from the result (which is a map) take the value for key `email`.